# ASP.NET Core Template Pack and angular 1 app in same project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, templates, webpack

I have successfully created an Angular 2 app using [ASP.NET Core Template Pack][1]
[1]: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

Everything is working fine, no issues.

But now I have an Angular 1 App created (working on a different MVC controller) with Typescript in another folder (all are .ts files). I need to configure the project to create .js file whenever I update the Angular 1 app.

Can I place a tsconfig.json file to create .js file to a folder from the Angular 1 app? Can someone please let me know the steps to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question,

Current "webpack.config.js" has the

```
    module.exports = [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

Create a separate config section after exciting config like this

```
    var ng1appConfig = merge(sharedConfig, 
    {
        entry: 
        {
            fileName1: './ClientApp/app/folder/fileName1.ts',
            fileName2: './ClientApp/app/folder/fileName2.ts',
            ......
            ......
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/ng1app'),
            filename: "[name].js"
        }
    });

    module.exports =[clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig, ng1appConfig ];
```

this will create .js file for each .ts file in the output folder

Have Fun

NeroIsNoHero